# Why is my wifi invisible to some devices? (Asus DSL-N17U)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I bought Asus DSL-N17U few months ago as my old router stopped working. Everything has worked fine for some time (internet, wifi, lan, ...).

However, few days ago two of our home devices stopped seeing the wifi (while some others still see and connect to it). The two devices (laptops) I'm writing about are different brands (Dell and Lenovo) with different operating systems (Windows7 and Ubuntu 15.04) and the are about 3-4 years old. What's really weird is that they both couldn't see the wifi anymore at the same time, hence I assume the problem is the router.

Some info:

- DSL driver version: FwVer:5.5.1.135_B_A60901 HwVer:T14.F7_0.2
- Firmware version: 1.1.0.4 (up-to-date)
- Hide SSID: No
- Wireless Mode: Auto
- b/g protection: No (neither yes nor no works)
- Channel bandwidth: 20/40MHz
- Control Channel: Auto
- Extension Channel: Auto
- Authentication Method: WPA2-Personal
- WPA Encryption: AES
- Network Key Rotation Interval: 3600

I didn't change anything but SSID and password. Could you please help me? Possibly I must configure something? I'm really desperate.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the router? Rebooting the problematic WiFi devices?

Comment: @boot13 Yes I have rebooted everything I could but without any effect. There is an accepted answer below that helped me. Anyway thank you for your time and interest :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain wireless cards don't see some channels, namely 12 and 13. Try setting the channel to 1 and checking again.

Comment: Omg thank you so much! This really helped. I struggled with it for almost 3 days.

Comment: Could of been many other things. Wifi is one of IT's 'Dark Arts'. Some European spec wifi cards can only see channels 1-11 - Your router must of been using the extra non-EU channels.

Comment: oh yes, it offers channels up to 13